# Every time I open my local github I get an email saying that a new SSH key has been generated. Why is this? Is it bad?

Tags: github, ssh

I am new to Github, which I use solely for local version management. I notice, however, that every time I open Github I get an email saying that a new SSH key has been generated (from my computer - so no third party seems to be involved).
I don't understand why this is happening. I don't know whether it is a problem.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What program and OS are you using?

Comment: OS: El Capitan 10.11.6. I do not understand the question "what program?": I am not using any program, I am just opening github.

Comment: I don't see how opening GitHub.com in a browser would generate an SSH key.